PrivateBin container on Podman fails irregularly on restart (".s6-svscan/control: no such file or directory")
...

starting container 0e...b5: runc: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "tmpfs" to rootfs at "/run": tmpcopyup: failed to copy /run to /proc/self/fd/6 (/tmp/runctop961602072/runctmpdir3428808576): lchown /tmp/runctop961602072/runctmpdir3428808576/services/.s6-svscan/control: no such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found

Error: failed to start 1 containers

I get the above error intermittently when starting a pod from kubernetes yaml via podman kube play pod.yml. It occurs after an irregular number of restarts (between one and dozens) and is repoducible on multiple servers. Stopping, removing and restarting the pod anew does not fix the problem; after a podman system reset, podman unshare mkdir -p ...storage/volumes/privatebin/privatebin/srv/data and podman kube play pod.yml, the privatebin container (and therefore the entire pod) starts and runs as expected.
It seems to me that the container sometimes doesn't shut down cleanly. The podman system reset method works, but removes the PVCs, including saved data. I'm not sure as to how to best start troubleshooting the error. I'm happy to post snippets of the pod.yml as required.
The container image in question:
$ podman inspect 710dddbffd16 | jq -r '[.][][] | .Config'
{
  "User": "65534:82",
  "ExposedPorts": {
    "8080/tcp": {}
  },
  "Env": [
    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/srv/bin",
    "CONFIG_PATH=/srv/cfg"
  ],
  "Entrypoint": [
    "/etc/init.d/rc.local"
  ],
  "Volumes": {
    "/run": {},
    "/srv/data": {},
    "/tmp": {},
    "/var/lib/nginx/tmp": {}
  },
  "WorkingDir": "/var/www",
  "Labels": {
    "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "support@privatebin.org",
    "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://github.com/PrivateBin/docker-nginx-fpm-alpine/blob/master/README.md",
    "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "zlib-acknowledgement",
    "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/PrivateBin/docker-nginx-fpm-alpine",
    "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "PrivateBin",
    "org.opencontainers.image.version": "1.7.1"
  }
}

Podman debug info:
$ podman info --debug | sed '/\(hostname\|gitlab\)/d'
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.33.8
  cgroupControllers: []
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.1.10-1.module+el8.10.0+21962+8143777b.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.10, commit: 8f1552a71b76511fb9b4a96282513d17686c56fc'
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 98.25
    systemPercent: 0.6
    userPercent: 1.14
  cpus: 2
  databaseBackend: sqlite
  distribution:
    distribution: rhel
    version: "8.10"
  eventLogger: file
  freeLocks: 2040
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 368
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 300000
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 368
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 300000
      size: 65536
  kernel: 4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: k8s-file
  memFree: 7165800448
  memTotal: 8037998592
  networkBackend: cni
  networkBackendInfo:
    backend: cni
    dns:
      package: podman-plugins-4.9.4-4.module+el8.10.0+21995+81e8507c.x86_64
      path: /usr/libexec/cni/dnsname
      version: |-
        CNI dnsname plugin
        version: 1.4.0-dev
        commit: unknown
        CNI protocol versions supported: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 1.0.0
    package: containernetworking-plugins-1.4.0-2.module+el8.10.0+21962+8143777b.x86_64
    path: /usr/libexec/cni
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.1.12-1.module+el8.10.0+21974+acd2159c.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version 1.1.12
      spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.21.7 (Red Hat 1.21.7-2.module+el8.10.0+21638+b01be198)
      libseccomp: 2.5.2
  os: linux
  pasta:
    executable: ""
    package: ""
    version: ""
  remoteSocket:
    exists: false
    path: /run/user/368/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.2.3-1.module+el8.10.0+21962+8143777b.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.2.3
      commit: c22fde291bb35b354e6ca44d13be181c76a0a432
      libslirp: 4.4.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.2
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 0h 16m 40.00s
  variant: ""
plugins:
  authorization: null
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
store:
  configFile: /home/privatebin/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 4
    paused: 0
    running: 4
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /home/privatebin/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 1063256064
  graphRootUsed: 415830016
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Supports shifting: "false"
    Supports volatile: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 3
  runRoot: /run/user/368/containers
  transientStore: false
  volumePath: /home/privatebin/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 4.9.4-rhel
  Built: 1718703254
  BuiltTime: Tue Jun 18 11:34:14 2024
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.21.7 (Red Hat 1.21.7-2.module+el8.10.0+21638+b01be198)
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 4.9.4-rhel

